# Can you store an image in a form collection in ASP.NET MVC Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, razor, formcollection

I have a form in which I need to submit an image to the database. The rest of my form elements are surrounded by the Razor Form Tag, and I am accessing all the content through a FormCollection, via an Action by HttpPost. Can the image be accessed through the FormCollection? Sorry, I am new to ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Unless something's changed, I think in this case you'd want to add an `HttpPostedFile` to the action method signature.  (Or, if you're using the `Request` object, which you really shouldn't be in MVC, then the `Request.Files` collection should have it.)  Also make sure the form is `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

Comment: Thanks for the help!